# SP-API - Upload user manual

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I received an email from Amazon saying that user manuals for my online offers are required.

My question is how I can implement this with the SP API.

Is it correct to use UploadsV20201101Api.php for this?

The manuals should be listed later under “Product Documents” and assigned to different ASINS when uploaded.

Or is another library used for this?